# How to reproduce C# SDK's Scorable behaviour on NodeJs SDK on BotBuilder from BotFramework?

Tags: c#, node.js, botframework

I'm working on proactive notifications for a bot and I've found an example using the [C# SDK's Scorable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.scorables.iscorable-2?view=botbuilder-3.8) class.

C# docs:

I've tried to reproduce the behaviour with the NodeJs SDK and I've realized that I can trigger a dialog by using [.TriggerAction()](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.simpledialog.html#triggeraction), but I don't know how to assign a (weighting / priority) to the dialogs to know how important the notification could be.

Any idea on how to reproduce it?